# Angular routing mat-accent not working properly

Tags: angular, typescript, opencv, routes, angular-material

I inserted this **mat-button-toggle button** to my code. *About* and *Contacts* pages works fine except *Home* page button is always with mat-accent atribute. How to make it work only on the one I click on?

```
<mat-button-toggle routerLink="/contacts"routerLinkActive="mat-accent">Contacts</mat-button-toggle>

<mat-button-toggle routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="mat-accent">About</mat-button-toggle>

<mat-button-toggle routerLink="/"routerLinkActive="mat-accent">Home</mat-button-toggle>
```

Comment: how is yout approuting conf ?

Comment: sorry didn't understood. Can you explain? @pc_coder